# Simplified Explanation of Backpropogation

Tags: javascript, neural-network

I've been trying to get into neural networking for a while and I've created a simple perceptron in JavaScript as a test. The one thing holding me back is backpropogation. Every single search engine result I've found seems to be too complex to easily understand.

My Perceptron code for reference:

```
class Perceptron {
  constructor(actFunc, inputs, bias, learningRate, normalizer){
    this.weights = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs; i++){
      this.weights[i] = Math.random();
    }
    this.activation = actFunc;
    this.bias = bias;
    this.normalizer = normalizer;
    this.learningRate = learningRate;
  }
  train(input, expected) {
    var result = this.evaluate(input);
    var error = expected - result;
    this.weights[0] += this.learningRate*(error)*input[0];
    this.weights[1] += this.learningRate*(error)*input[1];
    this.bias += this.learningRate*error;
    console.log("Train: " + input + ": " + result + " Error: " + error);
  }

  evaluate(input){
    return this.activation((this.weights[0]*this.normalizer(input[0]))+(this.weights[1]*this.normalizer(input[1])) + this.bias);
  }

}
```

I eventually wanted to be able to string these together into a function neural network, but as I've stated, I hit a roadblock.

Comment: You'll have to write the code for that yourself but for simple explanation of back propagation you can refer to this video here.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=An5z8lR8asY

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. Im not looking for someone to write the code for me just to explain the mathematics